# Why doesn't Java initialize Array Objects?

Tags: java, arrays

If one runs the following code in java:

```
public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestObject[] array = new TestObject[4];
        //array[0] = new TestObject();
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array));
    }
}

class TestObject {
    String aString;

    public TestObject() {
        aString = "This has been initialized.";
    }
}
```

It will print (null, null, null, null), and if `array[0] = new TestObject();` is uncommented, then the first object will have a memory address (and not be null). I'm just confused to as to why Java wouldn't automatically call the constructor for each Object in an array when the array is first initialized properly. What are the advantages of the way it works right now? Is it a space issue (as in it would be too costly to do so)?

Maybe I've just overlooked something silly or I'm simply mistaken. This is not directly related to a problem I'm having, so if it's the wrong forum I apologize.

Comment: What happens if you want to fill up your array with real objects that are subclasses of TestObject, or which are constructed with non-default constructors?  In the real world, you rarely want an array with a bunch of identical objects.

Comment: It does initialize them ... just to the *default value* of the type. Doing otherwise quickly breaks down when sub-types or non-default constructors are used.

Comment: @Paul Ah, I see. The non-default constructor argument makes a lot of sense. Well, if you were to post your comment as an answer, I would be more than happy to accept it.

Comment: What if you applied the same logic to a list?  I create a list, and I know it will contain ten Strings, so should I auto populate that with new empty Strings?

Comment: @AmirAfghani If you *want* 10 empty strings .. since the size of a List can [usually] change, one generally just *doesn't add* "empty values" to it .. (as that can be represented by lack-of-item-in-list in most cases). In any case there are various `Array.fill` methods.

Comment: @AmirAfghani, Good point, but that's a little different I think.

Comment: I think @AmirAfghani's point is that filling any collection class with a bunch of identical objects is almost never what you want.  Why create objects that you're immediately going to have to replace (and GC)?

Comment: This is indeed what he meant.

Comment: Or the constructor could be private, or there might not be a default constructor, or...

Comment: @Kgrover, do tell how it's different.  The only difference I see is that an arrays size is declared upfront.

Comment: Oops, I completely misunderstood/misread your first comment-- my bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What happens if you want to fill up your array with real objects that are subclasses of TestObject, or which are constructed with non-default constructors? In the real world, you rarely want an array with a bunch of identical objects.

Comment: Additionally, not all objects _have_ "default constructors."

Answer (score 0):

With `new TestObject[4]` you create an array, wich can hold 4 references to `TestObject`.
So understand the difference between `TestObject[]` and `TestObject`:

`TestObject[]` is a reference store for `TestObject` - objects. If you create a `List<TestObject>` you'll have to fill up the list with references too.